# Was Hagrid ever compensated for his wrongful expulsion?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

In the early chapters of *Philosopher's Stone*, when Harry presses Hagrid about his time at Hogwarts, Hagrid tells Harry that he was expelled and banned from doing magic (for reasons that come to light in the *Chamber of Secrets*). After Harry finds out that the reasons for Hagrid's expulsion were actually due to the actions of Tom Riddle, did Hagrid get anything in the way of compensation (i.e. being allowed to use magic again) to make up for his unjust expulsion and ban from magic?

EDIT: I know Hagrid was able to do simple spells (i.e. lighting the fire in the lighthouse, and causing the boat to row itself from the lighthouse) using his primitive "wand-umbrella", but he asked Harry not to mention the how he had used said magic to anyone at Hogwarts; indicating he wasn't supposed to.

Comment: It's not a "primitive wand-umbrella", it's his normal wand! Bought from Ollivander's and restored by Dumbledore. Hagrid can't do complex magic because he didn't complete his education.

Comment: IIRC Dumbledore still has no way to *prove* Hagrid is innocent...

Comment: @Gallifreian No, Hagrid had his wand snapped in half and never repaired. It is heavily implied he fashioned the parts of his wand into the umbrella. But this was not a full repair and so nowhere near as powerful as his original wand

Comment: @user9429  -  if Hagrid's wand was snapped in half, he'd be performing magic like Ron in book 2, only worse - not performing at all. The implication is that his wand was snapped and the repaired by Dumbledore, or never snapped at all. He could have hidden his wand in an umbrella to conceal it from authorities, or to handle it better. See [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9949/why-didnt-hagrid-replace-augment-his-umbrella-which-had-shards-of-old-wand-wi?rq=1)

Comment: @Gallifreian see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/why-did-hagrids-umbrella-work-for-him

Comment: It's a speculation, just like mine. Except Dumbledore's Elder Wand has been seen fixing wands before, and we've never seen anyone effectively repairing a wand using non-magical means.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**YES**

While one can argue about forms of compensation, I am going to focus on your line "(i.e. being allowed to use magic again)". JK Rowling answered this herself back in a 2000 interview.

> Q: Since Hagrid's name was cleared in Book 2, will he ever be allowed to do magic openly again ? (Jan Campbell)
>
> A: He is allowed. **He has been allowed to do magic openly ever since he became a teacher** but because he was never fully trained his magic is never going to be what it should be. He is always going to be a bit inept.
>
> -*[World Exclusive Interview with J K Rowling](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-swns-alfie.htm)*, South West News Service, 8 July 2000

Also, remember Dumbledore hired him in the first place because he knew Hagrid was innocent but had no way to prove / convince the courts of this.

---

To address some of the concerns on Hagrid's wand this what Rowling has said on that

> Softballchicky32: What is the extent of Hagrid's magical powers?
>
> JK Rowling replies -> Not great! He can do magic to a fairly basic standard and occasionally surprises everyone (himself included) by bringing off more impressive bits of magic. Of course, he is somewhat hampered by the fact that **his wand is broken and disguised as an umbrella.**
>
> -[JK Rowling's World Book Day Chat, March 4, 2004](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm)

Comment: It would still be nice if Hagrid were compensated somehow for the fact that the wrongful expulsion has prevented him from receiving an education and provided lots of emotional anguish. If nothing else, a bag of Galleons would be a start.

Comment: @Thunderforge True that he deserves something more than the nothing he got. Being allowed to do magic again isn't really compensation-- if he'd never been falsely accused in the first place, he would've been able to do that anyways (and better, with a proper education). But the economics of HP are pretty weird, where the main consideration seems to be how hard a given bit of magic is to do, and so it's hard to "even out" what Hagrid lost by being a less able wizard overall.

Comment: It's not atypical of a government to correct its own mistakes as quietly as possible, especially when the ministers who committed the error are still in power.